# Recursively reverse string Java

Tags: java, string, recursion

I tried to recursively reverse a string in Java, but I am getting just the last character as output.

I looked up online and most of the codes have modified the input string. I am trying to build the output from empty string to reversed string. Please tell me what is wrong in my program.

```
class reverseStringRecursion
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println(reverse());
    }

    public static String reverse()
    {
        String strInput = " Hello I am my name.";
        String output = "";
        return recursiveHelper(strInput, 0, output);
    }

    public static String recursiveHelper(String strInput, int index, String output)
    {
        if(index == (strInput.length() - 1 ))
            output += strInput.charAt(index) + "";
        else
            output+= recursiveHelper(strInput, index + 1, output) +"";

        return output;
    }
}
```

The above code is returning output '.' only and nothing else. PLease help.

Comment: I recommend using your IDE's debugger. You can step through the code and see where your logic is going wrong.

Comment: "most of the codes have modified the input string". Not likely, java strings are immutable.

Comment: Your code never adds anything to the output but the last character. Note that you're calling `charAt()` only for the last character.

Comment: To reverse strings, you can also just use `new StringBuilder("text").reverse().toString()`

Comment: StackOverflow is not for your Computer Science homework. :-(

Comment: @Antares42 Its not my homework , if I posted my HW question on stackoverflow, I would be caught for plagarism !!!! :-)

Answer (score 4):

Others have done a good job of explaining why your code doesn't work. For comparison, here's a working version with some comments:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    System.out.println(reverse("Hello I am my name."));
}

public static String reverse(String text)
{
    // Base case:
    // If the string is empty, we're done.
    if (text.length() == 0) {
        return "";
    } else {
        // reverse("hello") = reverse("ello") + "h"
        return reverse(text.substring(1)) + text.charAt(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: @smartx thank you for the clear answer. Can you please explain how the reverse method loops over until the string is totally reversed? I mean there isn't any loop here.

Comment: The function is [_recursive_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)), which means it calls itself. The last line of the function says `return reverse(...);`, so it keeps calling itself over and over. That's the "loop."

Comment: okay. then how is it know when to end? and where is it keeping the currently recusing values?

Comment: The "base case" is the end. If the string is empty, then the function _doesn't_ call itself again. The values don't have to be explicitly kept anywhere... as the comment says, if the string is "hello", we just do `reverse("ello") + "h"`. While the recursive call is happening, the `"h"` is sort of waiting there. Once the recursive call returns "olle", the "h" gets stuck on to the end and we  get "olleh".

Answer (score 0):

Since `strInput` always contains the original String, the following condition makes sure your code only takes the last character of that String and ignore all the other characters:

```
if(index == (strInput.length() - 1 ))
    output += strInput.charAt(index) + "";
```

To build the reversed String recursively, you have to append the last character of the String to the reverse of the sub-string of the first length()-1 characters.

This means that you don't need the 2nd and 3rd arguments of your method, and `strInput` should be passed a shorter `String` in each recursive call.

```
public static String reverse (String strInput)
{
    if(strInput.length() <= 1)
        return strInput;
    else
        return strInput.charAt(strInput.length()-1) + reverse (strInput.substring(0,strInput.length()-1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `String` in Java are immuatable, passing it by parameter is useless on this case, so I removed it.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(reverse());
    }

    public static String reverse() {
        String strInput = " Hello I am my name.";
        return recursiveHelper(strInput, 0);
    }

    public static String recursiveHelper(String strInput, int index) {
        String output;
        if(index == (strInput.length() - 1 )){
            output = strInput.charAt(index) + "";
        }else{
            output = recursiveHelper(strInput, index + 1) + strInput.charAt(index);
        }
        return output;
    }
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZAxb4MwEIV3fsWJyVYS1MwRQ7dmyJSx6uDClTg1Btln1Kjit9MjUEIjIvUk6yT7u3fv@awatalqtOf8s@vq8G50BplR3sNBaQvfEXCN954UcWsqnUPJr@JITtsClCv865sc4b6OF09YJlWgpGaEjBUOG3QehZS7K9ZGC9Kj4MTOJYcnT25v60CQQgwvaEwFe1AllBewqsQk3k0TDik4yy0LzusGma7RiV@FNTz9y8rf6Tsba@B0fHL8WjDL@Zm5OdIf4opCmsLkIzFoCzpx2A1sQcqbSl@DBKed8Oyk3DOJcecK4lnkFo3HBwKP/2HwtIJtL7e8Z7bi/n/nIduo7bof)

Answer (score 0):

Modified your class:

```
public class ReverseStringRecursion {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println(reverse());
    }

    public static String reverse()
    {
        String strInput = "My Name is Jane Doe";
        String output = "";
        return recursiveHelper(strInput,0);
    }

    public static String recursiveHelper(String strInput, int index)
    {
        if(index == (strInput.length() - 1 ))
            return "" + strInput.charAt(index) ;
        else 
            return recursiveHelper(strInput,index+1) + strInput.charAt(index);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change your function *recursiveHelper()* to only receive one argument (the String that you want to reverse). Using the substring method from Java you can do it like this:

```
public static String recursiveHelper(String strInput) {
    if(strInput.length() == 1) {
        return strInput;
    }
    else if(strInput == "") {
        return "";
    }

    String subString1 = recursiveHelper(strInput.substring(0, strInput.length()/2));    // Here we copy the first half of the String to another String
    String subString2 = recursiveHelper(strInput.substring(strInput.length()/2));    // Here we do the same, but with the second half of the original String

    return susbString2 + subString1;    // It is very important that you sum the two substrings in this order!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str1="abc";
        String str2="";
        for(int i=str1.length()-1;i>=0;i--)
        {
          str2=str2+Character.toString(str1.charAt(i));
        }
        System.out.println("After Reverse: "+str2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Base case
if left>=right - do nothing

2) otherwise swap s[left] and s[right} and call helper(left+1, right-1)].

```
class Solution {
public void reverseString(char[] s) {
    int left = 0, right = s.length - 1;
    while (left < right) {
        char tmp = s[left];
        s[left++] = s[right];
        s[right--] = tmp;
    }
}
```

}